# spring data mongo db ldap authentication

Tags: mongodb, ldap

Our company recently changed from Basic auth to LDAP authentication and regular apps are now using `authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN` on the URL.

This works fine on a normal app but I can't figure out how to set these using Spring Data. Surely there is a way to do this, right?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're creating connection ?

Comment: I am using environment variables: export spring_data_mongodb_database=
export spring_data_mongodb_host=
export spring_data_mongodb_password=
export spring_data_mongodb_port=
export spring_data_mongodb_username=

Comment: So i haven't found any properties that will allow me to specify the authSource and authMechanism. The reason for the underscores (as opposed to dots) is that it is being deployed to OpenShift and that will convert the underscores to dots.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below you can't set something like authSource/authMechanism so you have to change to use URI. Also note when using URI you cannot use host/port and username/password. Those all need to go in the URI.

Something like

```
export spring_data_mongodb_database=db
export spring_data_mongodb_uri = mongodb://username:password@host:port?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN
```

Here all the properties that you can currently configure for mongodb in spring boot.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= # Authentication database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use.
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database= # GridFS database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost # Mongo server host.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server.
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # Mongo server port.
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # Enable Mongo repositories.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # Mongo database URI. When set, host and port are ignored.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server.
```

Comment: Thanks, the _uri was the key. I thought I had a problem with that before but maybe not.

Comment: did the answer work for you ? If yes please consider accepting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using Spring-Boot mongodb api with LDAP then the uri has to be the following in `application.properties` files in the `resources` folder:

  ```
  spring.data.mongodb.uri="mongodb://username:password@host:port/?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN"
  spring.data.mongodb.database="databasThatYouWantToConnectTo"
  ```
- No need for other parameters like `spring.data.mongodb.username`, `spring.data.mongodb.password`, etc., because everhything is mentioned in the `spring.data.mongodb.uri`
- the substring `authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN` in `spring.data.mongodb.uri` says Mongo that the authentication and authorization is by LDAP.
- You can check the image below which is taken from the [Connection String URI format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) document form MongoDB
  [image]
- If you are using the Mongo Java Driver provided by Mongo Db then you have to do the connection like this:

  ```
  import com.mongodb.MonogoClient;
  import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
  import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

  public class MongoConnect{
       public static void main(String args[]){
           MongoClientURI connString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://username:password@host:port/?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN");
           MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connString);
           MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("databasThatYouWantToConnectTo");
           System.out.println(database.getName()+" "+ mongoClient.getCredentialList());
      } 
  }
  ```